# click event on re-appended child in dom

Tags: javascript, dom, mouseevent

I'm trying to catch a `click` event on an element which changes its z-pos using `appendchild` on the `mousedown` event. The problem is that when you click an element when its not the front element then the `click` event doesn't fire. I know this is because it is removed from the DOM and then re-added but I'm not sure how I could fix it so that the click also fire when the element is moved to the front.

```js
MyObject = {
  init(parent, text) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.text= text;
    this.visual = document.createElement("div");
    this.visual.setAttribute("class", "object");
    this.visual.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text))
    parent.appendChild(this.visual);;
    
    this.visual.addEventListener("click", (e) => { this.onClicked(e); });
    this.visual.addEventListener("mousedown", (e) => { this.onMouseDown (e); });
  },
  
  toTop() {
    this.parent.appendChild(this.visual);
  },
  onClicked(e) {
    alert(this.text + " was clicked");
 e.stopPropagation();
  },
  onMouseDown(e) {
    this.toTop();
    // I'm also doing other things here
  }
};

var parent = document.querySelector(".parent");
parent.addEventListener("click", (e) => { alert("parent clicked"); });

var createObj = function(text) {
  var obj = Object.create(MyObject);
  obj.init (parent, text);
};

createObj ("object 1");
createObj ("object 2");
createObj ("object 3");
createObj ("object 4");
```

```css
.parent {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.object {
  background: #0F0;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  
</div>
```

So in this example you always have to click the bottom element to get the alert while I would also like to get the alert when an other items is pressed.

**edit:** I'm testing in chrome (55.0.2883.87) and the code might not work in other browsers.

Comment: When replacing nodes with events on them, you also have to rebind the event to the new node. The better solution is almost always to just bind the event to a parent container (that never gets removed) instead.

Comment: @Shilly if i rebind the event then it will be fired twice. I think the problem is that a `click` event is only triggered when the `mousedown` and `mouseup` happens on the same element and because of the potential remove in the append the DOM thinks it's another element.

Comment: It should always trigger twice, since every click will also produce a mousedown event. Anyways, the advice still stands, if you bind to the parent node instead, all your different div-children can share the same event handler and you don't have to rebind anything.

Comment: Ok, one of your problems is that arrow functions DONT bind their this context. so using `this.visual.addEventListener("click", (e) => { this.onClicked(e); });` means all your created objects will refer to the last object created or to the global window. So you probably want to bind them by replacing the event listeners to: `this.visual.addEventListener("click", function(e){this.onClicked(e);}.bind(this));` After binding the handlers to their own this context, I get an alert for any clicked row. But since the rows switch position everytime, it always depends a bit on how fast i click.

Comment: I mean that the click event is triggered twice. Adding the `click` event to the parent would indeed work but then I wouldn't be able to depent on the `this` binding and I would need to get a reference to the object from somewhere else. As far as I know the arrow function does bind the `this` context ([source](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/es6%20%26%20beyond/ch2.md#not-just-shorter-syntax-but-this)).

Comment: I trust the MDN reference more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions , but thanks for the link, I'll look into it. And euh, both the parent and the visual are in the same scope, so why would binding to the parent not point to the same this?

Comment: You're right in this specific case of using an arrow function and this as an event handler, since it will bind to the scope of the init function.

Comment: You were also right that it doesn't bind the this from the calling context (I've misread your sentence combined with the example and then incorrectly phrased it). I now get what you mean by binding it just to the parent :). In this example it would indeed work but in my actual code there is also an `click` event on the parent which has a different event. I'll update the example.

Comment: You can have multiple event handlers of the same type when you use addEventListener. And the event target will tell you if the parent or a child-div was clicked. Anyways, just making suggestions.

Comment: I just don't see that work with complex child objects and a more complex parent because the target could be any child of the child (child click) or a not related child of the parent (parent click).

Comment: I used to have the same issues with hundreds of event handlers on one page, so I switched to a single event handler model with one click/change/mouse handler on the body and then give every element that needs to be clicked an event name and an id that can be sent to the event mediator which triggers the respective module handler. This drastically simplified my event development in complex mashups and removed the need to reappend/rebind the events when I add new dynamically created DOM nodes.

Comment: Could you apply this on the given example so I could see how it would work

Comment: It's not a full example, but this is how I implement alot of these things. https://jsfiddle.net/qyu0ghw9/   The downside is that since I use strings to signify events, it minifies worse and breaks some browser optimalisations, but that can be partially solved by using an event dictionary instead of string literals.